# I am getting error when using pyttsx3.2.6 library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx

I am new to python, I am trying to use python offline text to speech library pyttsx3. While i am running following script

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I am talking now ");
engine.setProperty('rate',100)  
engine.runAndWait();
```

I am getting following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\care\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 44, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
    File "C:\Users\care\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
    KeyError

   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\care\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\hello.py", line 2, in <module>
   engine = pyttsx3.init()
   File "C:\Users\care\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 46, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
    File "C:\Users\care\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
    File "C:\Users\care\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 75, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
    File "C:\Users\care\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "C:\Users\care\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    import win32com.client
    File "C:\Users\care\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
   ImportError: No module named 'win32api'
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just solved my problem by restarting python shell and placing pythoncom35.dll and pywintypes35.dll from C:\Users\care\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\pypiwin32 to C:\Users\care\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\win32